# Trying to install vue cli but it results in errors

Tags: node.js, npm

This is the error message I getwhen trying to install vue cli
I'm using node version 12.13.1 and npm version 6.12.1.
Any help here please??

C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated shortid@2.2.16: Package no longer supported. Contact Support
at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...: https://openpgpjs
.o'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MARCUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-28T23_30_53
_884Z-debug.log

C:\Windows\system32>